# iPhone 3.1 SDK Camera Access

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera

How can I create an application that would initiate a camera and update the image view with the image picked by the camera?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

In the viewDidLoad method, initialize the UIImagePickerController, assign its property sourceType as UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera and delegate as self.

Define a button in your view controller where on its click event get the modal view of the imagepicker, like:

```
[self presentModalViewController:self.picker animated:YES];
```

here picker is the object of UIImagePickerController.

Next,implement the *didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo* delegate of UIImagePickerController. In this delegate, you can assign a UIImage to the Dictionary object info, then save the image to your local instance of UIImageView(its ImageToSave below)

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{ 

[[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerImage"];
ImageToSave.image = img;
```

}

Do not forget to include the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate into your main view controller's .h file.

See if this works or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it, `self.view = picker.cameraOverlayView` just copies an empty transparent view over you own!!  It doesn't even add it to the screen, not that it would work...

Instead, you need to present the picker controller:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Then make sure to implement the delegate calls (which it looks like you may have since you already set the delegate)